# Expression variable is not defined only in specific case

Tags: c#, .net, linq, variables, expression

This **works**.

`context => context.GetType().Name + '1'`

Expression type: `` System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1`1[System.Func`2[Namespace.Context,System.String]] ``

Body: `(context.GetType().Name + Convert(1, Object))`

IL:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Namespace.Context,System.String]>(Namespace.Context $context)
{
    (.Call $context.GetType()).Name + (System.Object)'1'
}
```

---

This does **not** work.

`context => context.Previous.Output["rate"].ToString()`

Expression type: `` System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1`1[System.Func`2[Namespace.Context,System.String]] ``

Body: `context.Previous.Output.get_Item("rate").ToString()`

IL:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Namespace.Context,System.String]>(Namespace.Context $context)
{
    .Call (.Call (($context.Previous).Output).get_Item("rate")).ToString()
}
```

The error is:
`variable 'context' of type 'Namespace.Context' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined`

Where is the difference for expression parser? In both cases context is defined as Context parameter inside expression. I have no ideas why the second is not compiling.
I'm using `Serialize.Linq` library to serialize expression. Maybe there is some bug inside and there are some expression transformations?

Comment: The variable may not be public or static.  VS will show what object are valid when you type the period.  Use this feature. When you type without using the VS selection you get errors like what you are seeing.

Comment: @jdweng Than why does the first lambda work?

Comment: What happens if you try to define a `Func` instead of an `Expression` in the same context?

Comment: @NetMage : The OP is using different table (classes) inside the context.  The following is not working : context.Previous.Output

Comment: @jdweng In that case I would suggest trying `context => contextPrevious.Output.GetType().Name + "1"` but the error message doesn't suggest that to me.

Comment: @NetMage : We do not know much about this issue except there either a typo or the class/property is not accessible.   That is why I said in my first comment that OP has let VS enter the variable names instead of OP typing the names.

Comment: If you mean VS = Visual Studio, then it has nothing to do with it, i'm creating expressions in plain text, sorry that didn't mention. BUT probably I resolved this, not in this concrete case, but I had exactly the same error with other expressions, building dynamically in the code this time and what was the problem - the lambda parameter outside lambda (passed into lambda) should be exactly the same object reference as parameter inside lambda. I was creating like 2 same parameters with same name before. With the same reference it works.